# Reliably getting a character count for .doc files

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, word-count, charactercount

What's a reliable way to automatically count the characters and/or words in a .doc or .docx file?

The only real requirement is a reasonably accurate and reasonably reliable count.
It needs to work with documents containing something other than Latin script, so counting characters is good enough for most cases.
The count does not necessarily need to match Word's, but the closer the better.
Since there are a gazillion different apps that can generate .doc files, it's okay to fail to count anything, but this case needs to be catchable so we're aware that a count may be inaccurate. For all other cases the count must be, say, at least 99% accurate at least 99% of the time.

I'm open as to the involved technologies, but something that can run on a *NIX command line would be greatly preferred.

Is there a reasonable solution for this?

Comment: You can use wvSummary(http://linux.die.net/man/1/wvsummary) if you can count it last being saved by Word (or at least a program that saves Word metadata).

Comment: @Matthew Unfortunately, relying on meta data in the files themselves is exactly what's too unreliable. :)

Comment: can you install word on a windows machine somewhere in your network and just use Word itself (via some COM or VBA) to get the exact count?

Comment: @Peter I was thinking about this option as well, but it would be my last resort. We have absolutely zero Windows infrastructure right now, so it would be quite a task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [link](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/52385?theme=print) to some Linux word-to-text converters.

For example you could use

```
antiword file.doc | wc
```

to do the counting.

Edit:

This [link](http://opensource.weblogsinc.com/2005/06/29/use-abiword-to-convert-filetypes-on-the-command-line/) shows that AbiWord has a command-line interface, that you could use to convert the .docx format to .txt and then count the words using "wc". AbiWord does support the docx format

Comment: Antiword looks pretty good, thanks. Any solution for .docx files though?

Comment: AbiWord might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X has support for reading word files built into the system frameworks, so if you have that, it's easy. MacRuby sample:

```
NSSpellChecker.sharedSpellChecker.countWordsInString(NSAttributedString.alloc.initWithURL(fileURL, documentAttributes:nil), language:nil)
```

More portably — though it gives up support for docx — you could simply get Antiword and do `antiword | wc -w`.

Comment: That might be a solution, though probably hard to use in production (Linux server). I'll look into it though...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has published a [specification](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/OfficeBinaryFormats.mspx) for the Office binary file formats. Parsing a .DOC file doesn't look trivial, but with some care you should be able to get a dependable, repeatable result. I have no idea how closely it'll match with what Word shows -- that will probably depend (at least partly) on how you define "word" -- for example, whether you consider a group of digits a "word" or not. It probably won't take a lot to figure out how Word treats cases like that, so getting a close match shouldn't be terribly difficult.

Comment: I am not intending to write my own .doc parser, thank you very much. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider online applications as a solution, yes, there is a solution.
This not so pretty (regarding the design) site offers both word and character count: http://allworldphone.com/count-words-characters.htm

I don't think there is a limit, and it shouldn't be a problem to just copy/paste the contents of your documents into the corresponding textarea and see the result.

Regarding the 100% or 99% accuracy, you could test it with a few (i.e. 20-50 words) by counting them yourself first.

I hope this helps.
Regards. Chris

Comment: I think the main problem is to get the plain text out of the word document without opening word (which is what deceze would have to do to cut and paste the contents)